# CKEditor5 and CKFinder Image URL

Tags: ckeditor5, ckfinder

When i select an image using the ckfinder the src value for the image contains "ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=...."

Whereas in the examples online, when you inspect the page to see the raw code.
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/demo/ckfinder3/samples/ckeditor.html#integration-ckeditor5

The scr value contains...
img src="https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/userfiles/images/...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any chance that you set useProxyCommand in the backend configuration? https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_backends

Comment: Many, many thanks Wiktor. Changing useProxyCommand to false. Resolved the issue.